# mysql import failed caused by overgrown general log file

Tags: mysql, import

I have a table about 70G in size. I took a backup using mysqldump.

In the new server, I performed a restoration.

```
time mysql -uroot -p TDB < TDB.sql
Enter password:
ERROR 3 (HY000) at line 58155: Error writing file '/app/mysql/admin/tmp/MLLVx92e' 
(Errcode: 28 - No space left on device)
```

Further checked, showed that the general log file in /app has increased tremendously.

```
show variables 'general_log_file'
general_log_file                        | /app/mysql/admin/mysql.log
```

Does importing using mysql causes general log file to grow exponentially?

Answer (score 1):

All statements that hit the server are stored inside the general log. So general log is duplicating your dump. The general log should be used only for debugging only, and it should be activated for the time required to spot a problem. Try to disactivate general log.

Answer (score 1):

The general log should never be enabled on a production server (under normal circumstances), as it logs absolutely all queries (reads and writes) performed on the server, taking a lot of disk space and query performance with it.

The general log is only useful for debugging issues on the server. You should turn it off on a live server by executing:

```
SET GLOBAL general_log = OFF;
```

And permanently by setting on your `my.cnf` or `my.ini`:

```
[mysqld]
general_log = 0
```

(or commenting the line with `general_log`). You should get something like this:

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES like 'general_log';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| general_log   | OFF   |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```